# How to efficiently get specific value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, for-loop

I have an array like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(15) "Company A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(6) "100"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(9) "Company B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(6) "150"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(13) "Company C"
    ["value"]=>
    string(6) "200"
  }
}
```

Now I want to get all company names and concatenate them by commata. I can go like this:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $companies[] = $a['company'];
}
$company_names = implode(',', $companies);
var_dump($company_names);
```

Prints

```
string(29) "Company A,Company B,Company C"
```

So to say: It works. But this seems inefficient to me, that thing with the loop.

Are there more efficient ways to come to the same result? E.g. using `array_keys` or stuff?

Comment: I doubt it. To get values you must loop through it one way or another.

Comment: Are you suggesting built in functions don't loop? For this to be considered inefficient you'd need a lot more than 3 companies. In general this sort of processing is pretty low on system requirements. When in doubt, benchmark, or write a caching script.

Comment: I agree, I think you as good as you are going to get. Might be an optimization made where you are building the array.

Comment: @KaiQing: No I'm not suggesting that other functions don't use this algorithm. I am referring to the efficiency of my code (=less lines for same result), not of the implementation in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_column()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) but it requires PHP version greater than 5.5:

```
$array = array_column($companies, 'company');
echo implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: and there are some solutions in php < 5.5 in the manual comments

Comment: [For php < 5.5](http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) as suggested by *Fu Xu*:

```
$array = array_column($companies, 'company');
echo implode(',', $array);
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/50854)

Answer (score 1):

> Are there more efficient ways to come to the same result?

*Efficient* is a broad term. I'll assume *efficient* to mean *native*. In which case, yes, in PHP 5.5+ you can use `array_column()` as [answered by Fu Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034332/164998).

Otherwise, in PHP < 5.5, no. That is there is nothing *native*. While you could combine any of the dozens of native [PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to achieve the same thing, they're simply more ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Well, as mentioned in a comment above, efficient means in this case: Less lines of code for the same result.

Comment: The answer remains the same. Less lines of code is not always better. Be *clearer* not *cleverer*.